# Find all order 3 elements of S6 that commute with (135).

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm new to abstract algebra, and I'm looking for an explanation for this problem: **Find all order 3 elements of** $S_6$ **that commute with (135).**

My intuition was to use, I think it is a theorem, the idea that for an element in a permutation group to commute with another, it needs to be from a disjoint cycle (so no element in common). Thus, $${(264),(246),(135)(246),(135)(264)}$$ are elements that commute with (135), but my answer is wrong.

The answer is:

$${(135), (153), (246), (264), (135)(246), (135)(264), (153)(246), (153)(264)}$$

Not sure to understand why elements with 1, 3 or 5 can commute as they are not a disjoint cycle with (135).

Comment: Since the cyclic group generated by $(135)$ has group order $3$, it certainly contains some elements that are not disjoint cycle with $(135)$

Comment: Ok, if the question would have mentioned: find a subgroup of S6 that commutes with (135) but is not cyclic. Then, my answer would work, right?

Comment: That's right with the assumption. But I think your original answer should inculde $(1)$, the identity element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because... $(153)=(135)^2$!

I'll let $(135)=\sigma, (246)=\tau$, then $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$. And your 8 answer is represented by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ by...

$$
(135)=\sigma
\\
(153)=\sigma^2
\\
(246)=\tau
\\
(264)=\tau^2
\\
(135)(246)=\sigma\tau
\\
(135)(264)=\sigma\tau^2
\\
(153)(246)=\sigma^2\tau
\\
(153)(264)=\sigma^2\tau^2.$$

They all commute with $\sigma=(135)$.

Comment: So, basically an element commute with every element it generates and it commutes with disjoint cycles? For permutation group

Comment: Oh, no @TheMathAI. $(1234)$ and $(1324)$ cannot be commute.

Comment: Because these elements are not a disjoint cycle? and they are not part of the same cycle? Maybe, I never had the right definition for disjoint cycles, but I thought it meant that it contained no common number in order to be considered a disjoint cycle. Example: (123) and (456) are disjoint, but (123) and (451) are not disjoint.

Comment: @TheMathAI, Surely $(135)$ and $(153)$ is not disjoint. But disjoint is not a point. $(153)=(135)^2$ is a point.

Comment: What do you mean by "is a point".